# gridview inside tab fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview, android-fragments

I need help with my project, I  was following this tutorial I found that creating an app with navigation drawer and tabs, when you run the app it will look like this:

[image]

and I was trying to change view inside the tab fragment with `GridView`, so I need help anyone could tell me where and how should I add the `GridView`

so here's my main activity java :

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MenuUtama extends ActionBarActivity{

    Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
    public DaftarMakanan foodList;
    GridView makananGrid;

    ViewPager viewPager;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_utama);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        NavDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.MyPager);
        mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        mTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyTabs);
        mTabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        mTabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabsText);
        mTabs.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        mTabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.brown));

        mTabs.setViewPager(mPager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_utama, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This Is " + item.getTitle() + " Button",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.bill) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, BillTagihanAnda.class));
        }

        if (id == R.id.pesanan) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, DaftarPesananAnda.class));
        }

        if (id == R.id.callwaiter) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PanggilPelayan.class));
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        int icon[] = { R.drawable.ic_food, R.drawable.ic_drink, R.drawable.ic_desserts };
        String[] tabsText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);


        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabsText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance(position);
            return myFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(icon[position]);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
            ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" ");
            spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, spannableString.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            return spannableString;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        private TextView textView;
        private GridView gridView;

        public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("position", position);
            myFragment.setArguments(args);
            return myFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
            textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
            gridView = (GridView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                textView.setText("The Page Selected is " + bundle.getInt("position"));
            }

            return layout;
        }

    }

}
```

my main activity xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="id.WKKR.ktcafe.MenuUtama" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <tabs.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/MyTabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/MyPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="id.WKKR.ktcafe.NavDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_nav_drawer_fragment"
        yourapp:layout="@layout/activity_nav_drawer_fragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and my fragment xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/position"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Page Number 1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

(Edited)
so I change the fragment xml with `GridView`,and now where should I put the adapter for the `GridView` to show data, should I create new adapter class or just add the adapter inside main activity java class? :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform" >

</GridView>
```

Comment: Whatever you want on your tab, you add it to your fragment, not your main activity. Your tab is a canvas, and you lay on top of it fragment.xml. So change your fragment.xml to have the gridview.

Comment: @sparkysword ok i already change the textview in fragment xml with gridview, now to show the data inside gridview, where should i create the adapter? should i create new adapter class, or just put the adapter class inside main activity class? thanks for your help.

Comment: i finally able to make it done, thanks @sparkysword, you enlightened me. really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

i finally figure it out

so i create a new adapter class to inflate the grid content

so here's my grid adapter class called food adapter :

```js
package id.WKKR.ktcafe;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FoodAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 ArrayList<Menus> list;
 Context context;

 FoodAdapter(Context context) {
  this.context = context;
  list = new ArrayList<Menus>();
  Resources res = context.getResources();
  String[] tempMenusNames = res.getStringArray(R.array.food);
  String[] tempMenusPrices = res.getStringArray(R.array.foodprices);
  int[] menusImages = { R.drawable.makanana, R.drawable.makananb,
    R.drawable.makananc, R.drawable.makanand, R.drawable.makanane,
    R.drawable.makananf };
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   Menus tempMenus = new Menus(menusImages[i], tempMenusNames[i],
     tempMenusPrices[i]);
   list.add(tempMenus);
  }

 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return list.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int i) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return list.get(i);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int i) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return i;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  ViewHolder holder = null;
  if (row == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
   holder = new ViewHolder(row);
   row.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
  }

  Menus temp = list.get(i);
  holder.myMenus.setImageResource(temp.imageId);
  holder.myMenusText.setText(temp.menus);
  holder.MyMenusPrice.setText(temp.menusPrices);

  return row;
 }

 class ViewHolder {
  ImageView myMenus;
  TextView myMenusText;
  TextView MyMenusPrice;

  ViewHolder(View v) {
   myMenus = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   myMenusText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   MyMenusPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  }
 }

 class Menus {
  int imageId;
  String menus;
  String menusPrices;

  Menus(int imageId, String menus, String menusPrices) {
   this.imageId = imageId;
   this.menus = menus;
   this.menusPrices = menusPrices;
  }
 }

}
```

the getView method inside the food adapter will inflate an xml called single_item.xml, which look like this :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/makanana" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Rp. " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then in my main activity java, i get the reference of my gridview in my_fragment.xml and the adapter as well, then set the adapter in onCreateView method.

```js
public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  private TextView textView;
  
        //add gridview and foodadapter in fragment
  private GridView gridView;
  private FoodAdapter foodAdapter;

  public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
   MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putInt("position", position);
   myFragment.setArguments(args);
   return myFragment;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
            
            //and here i get the reference of gridview from my_fragment.xml and set the adapter
   gridView = (GridView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
   foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(getActivity());
   gridView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);

   return layout;
  }

 }
```

when you run the app it will look like this pict : http://i61.tinypic.com/9sgsjs.jpg.